# How to initialize a jagged array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jagged-arrays

Is it possible to have a jagged array in JavaScript?

Here is the format of the data I want to store in a jagged array:

```
(key)(value1, value2, value3)
```

Can I put this in a jagged array?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can create that type of array using object or array literal grammar, or object/array methods.

An array of arrays:

```
// Using array literal grammar
var arr = [[value1, value2, value3], [value1, value2]]

// Creating and pushing to an array
var arr = [];
arr.push([value1, value2, value3]);
```

An object of arrays:

```
// Using object literal grammar
var obj = { "key": [value1, value2, value3], "key2": [value1, value2] } 

// Creating object properties using bracket or dot notation
var obj = {};
obj.key = [value1, value2, value3];
obj["key2"] = [value1, value2];
```

Comment: okay, so using your "Creating object properties using bracket or dot notation" example i could get at a certain value in the following alert?:   alert(obj["key2"][])

Comment: @William: yes, `alert(obj["key2"][0])` would alert the value of `value1`, `alert(obj["key2"][1])` would alert the value of `value2`.